# Generic Producer-Consumer in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, template, producer-consumer

I wrote the following simple 1 producer - 1 consumer problem, in attempt to learn some C++11 threading / generics.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <deque>
#include <thread>

struct data {
    int x, y;
    std::string s;

    data() : s("test") {
        x = std::rand() % 1000000;
        y = std::rand() % 1000000;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const struct data d) {
        os << d.x << ", " << d.y << ", " << d.s << "\n";
    }
};


typedef struct data elem_t;

template <typename T>
class Buffer 
{
public:
    Buffer(): m_size(1) {}
    Buffer(int s): m_size(s) {}

    void add(T x) {
        while (true) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m_mtx);
            m_cond.wait(locker, [this](){return m_buffer.size() < m_size;});

            m_buffer.push_back(x);

            locker.unlock();
            m_cond.notify_all();

            return;
        }
    }

    T remove() {
        while (true) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m_mtx);
            m_cond.wait(locker, [this](){return m_buffer.size() > 0;});

            T x = m_buffer.back();
            m_buffer.pop_back();

            locker.unlock();
            m_cond.notify_all();

            return x;
        }
    }

private:
    std::mutex m_mtx;
    std::condition_variable m_cond;

    std::deque<T> m_buffer;
    unsigned int m_size;
};



template <typename T>
class Producer
{
public:
    Producer() : m_buf(nullptr) {}
    Producer(std::string&& id, Buffer<T> *buf) : m_id(id), m_buf(buf) {}

    void produce() {
        while (true) {
            T x = T();

            m_buf->add(x);
            std::cout << x;

            int sleep = std::rand() % 1000 + 10;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(sleep));
        }
    }

private:
    Buffer<T> *m_buf;
    std::string m_id;
};



template <typename T = int>
class Consumer
{
public:
    Consumer() : m_buf(nullptr) {}
    Consumer(std::string&& id, Buffer<T> *buf) : m_id(id), m_buf(buf) {}

    void consume() {
        while(true) {
            T x = m_buf->remove();
            std::cout << x;

            int sleep = std::rand() % 1000 + 10;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(sleep));
        }
    }

private:
    Buffer<T> *m_buf;
    std::string m_id;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::srand(std::time(nullptr));

    Buffer<elem_t> *buffer = new Buffer<elem_t>(std::stoi(argv[1]));
    Producer<elem_t> *p = new Producer<elem_t>("prod", buffer);
    Consumer<elem_t> *c = new Consumer<elem_t>("cons", buffer);

    std::thread pt(&Producer<elem_t>::produce, p);
    std::thread ct(&Consumer<elem_t>::consume, c);

    pt.join();
    ct.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The main concern I am having with this code is regarding genericity. 
I have a generic buffer `Buffer<T>` (which is basically a `std::deque<T>`) and the produced value: `T x = T();`

For now, `T = struct data`, and everything works because of `data()`, but if `T = int`, for example, things start to get ugly.

One idea I have is to define a `struct data` packing all the needed fields, and then remove templates from classes (i.e. `std::deque<struct data>` only).

So, are templates an *overkill* here, and if not what is the / a *correct* way of expressing this code with them?
Also, are there any other problems / code smells / things to improve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `Buffer<T>`

This class seems fine for the most part. Some small issues:

- The `while(true)` loops in `insert(T)` and `remove()` only ever run one iteration. Those loops can be replaced by their body.
- `add` calls `m_buffer.push_back(x)`, which might not compile for types without a copy constructor. Try `m_buffer.push_back(std::move(x))` instead: That will move if possible, and fall back to copy if not.
- `m_buffer` is treated like a stack (`push_back` and `pop_back` are used only), so newest insertions get removed first. Maybe a queue was intended (using e.g. `push_front` and `pop_back`)?
- The constructors initialize `Buffer<T>::m_size` (an `unsigned int`) with a signed value (`1` or `int s`, respectively).
- `notify_all()` is called on the condition variable. This would wake up every thread waiting on it - but very likely only one would actually be able to do anything. `notify_one()` would likely be a better fit.
- The `notify_all` calls on the condition variable aren't needed every time: `remove` only needs to notify if other threads might be waiting to `add` elements, which is only when `m_buffer.size() == m_size - 1` after the call to `pop_back`. Similarly, `add` only needs to notify if `m_buffer.size() == 1` after `push_front`.
- `Buffer<T>::m_size` doesn't represent the current size of the buffer (= number of elements contained), but the maximum capacity. Maybe `m_capacity` would be a better name.
- `Buffer` itself isn't very descriptive of what it actually does. `ConcurrentQueue`, `MessageQueue` or similar would better represent its behavior.
- While `add` and `remove` by themselves are fine names, common expectation for queue-like types are `push` and `pop`.
- This actually is a working queue for n producers and m consumers. It seems a bit overkill for a 1 producer + 1 consumer scenario.

Furthermore, some improvements could be made:

- `bool try_push(T&&)`/`bool try_push(const T&)`/`bool try_pop(T&)` member functions could be added that return early if the operation would otherwise have to wait.
- `push` could be overloaded for `const T&` and `T&&` to enable better performance for moveable types.

## `Producer<T>`/`Consumer<T>`

Both of these don't really seem necessary. Generally, its unlikely that someone will ever need generic producers/consumers (other than maybe for testing purposes), so I won't go into too much detail

- Default constructors initialize `m_buf` to `nullptr`, but this is never checked afterwards. Either add checks for `nullptr` in the other member functions, or simply remove the default constructor.
- Similarly, the `buf` parameter of the other constructor can be `nullptr`. If `m_buf` should never be `nullptr` (as the member functions seem to assume), simply make `buf` a `Buffer<T>&` instead. `m_buf` could then be initialized to `&buf` - but it might be more reasonable to change `m_buf` to `Buffer<T>&`, too.
- Access to `std::cout` isn't synchronized. In some cases, this means the consumer might print before the producer does.
- There is no way to stop a producer/consumer (other than forcefully terminating the program).
- The member `m_id` is never used.
- The second constructor takes a `std::string&& id` parameter - but initializes `m_id` without moving - which creates a copy. Generally, it would be expected that the object `id` refers to would be moved from after construction.

## General stuff

- `main` never checks if `argv[1]` is actually valid.
- Using `struct data` when referencing the type isn't necessary in C++, just `data` suffices. So `typedef struct data elem_t;` could be simplified to `typedef data elem_t;`, or with a more modern approach, `using elem_t = data;`. (The `struct data` would be necessary in C, but this code will never interact with C as C doesn't support templates anyways.)
- Many places use parentheses to initialize objects, like `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m_mtx);`. Prefer braces `{}` instead: In the example, if `m_mtx` could be interpreted as a type, then the compiler would be forced to make `locker` a function declaration. Using braces would prevent that from happening.
- Prefer the utilities in the `<random>` header for generating random numbers, as `std::rand` is kinda terrible.
- There's no need to create `buffer`, `p` and `c` on the heap (inside `main`). Using local variables would be just fine. (Also, they never get `delete`d properly. If allocation on the heap is absolutely needed, prefer using smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.)
- I cannot think of a 1 producer/1 consumer scenario in which threads are necessary: Most could be simplified to this pseudocode:

  ```
  int main() {
      while(keep_running()) {
          consume_one(produce_one());
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: _it's unlikely that someone will ever need generic producers/consumers_
I understand this, but how can `Producer` contain a `Buffer<T>` member variable without using a `template <typename T> class Producer` definition?

Comment: @Alex: `class ItemProducer { Buffer<Item>& queue; };` (assuming an actual `Item` class). A specific producer knows which type of objects it's going to produce.

Comment: In other words, the `template<typename T>` part of the `Buffer` class just leaves a blank to be filled in later. The `Producer` can explicitly fill that blank (see `Item` in the comment above), or delegate that decision upwards (where it is instantiated).by making itself a class template.

Comment: @DavideSpataro: `add` currently takes a `T x` parameter, i.e. the caller already made an independent copy. Moving from `x` won't affect anything on the callers site, it just uses a possibly faster move operation where available. (Also, `x` is never used in `add` afterwards.) // `T&&` is not a universal reference in this context, as `T` doesn't get deduced for the `add` call (it got declared/deduced earlier with `Buffer<T>`s construction), so `T&&` is an actual rvalue reference in this context. (Also, I already mentioned adding overloads for `const T&` and `T&&`)

Comment: @hoffmale your're definitely right. always good to learn something.